# How to draw linear trend with lm or abline in R

Tags: r

I am a complete newbie in R, and I have a problem with linear trend fitting.

My data is daily financial data for around 4 years. The financial year is 260 days (5 days a week) so the total amount of data is 913. 
For the simplicity, the data is only one cloumb with 913 data and with one header.

I can plot the time series data without problem. But when I try to plot linear trend with lm, I can get the error message: 
"formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula"

And when I try to plot the linear trend with abline, I get the error message: 
"Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

My code is below. So can anyone help me draw linear trend with lm or abline? I check the web to see how lm or abline is used. Some examples used "formula" for lm and abline, but I didn't understand what kind of formula i should use.

```
SE=read.csv(file="SE1.csv",head=TRUE,sep="") 
Price<-SE$Closingprice 
Price.SEK<-ts(Price, start=2011) 
plot(Price.SEK,main="Stockholm 30 Index from August 2011 to March 2015",lwd=1,col=4) 
str(Price.SEK) 
lm.01<-lm(Price.SEK)
```

Comment: `lm()` needs a response and predictor variables in the formula. What's the linear model you are trying to fit here?

Comment: What do you mean with the linear model? It is a non-seasonal time series with "almost" constant trend slope.
Do you mean the trend solving method, like the least square method? If you mean that, then my answer is yes. I can use the least-square method. or even I can use the "differencing" method.

Comment: `lm` needs a format like `lm(y ~ x)` - at the moment you don't have an `x` - representing the time elapsed for each `y` value. You can't get a correlation with only one variable. Maybe you need `lm(y ~ time(y))` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. I solved the problem as below:

    SE=read.csv(file="SE.csv",head=TRUE,sep=";")

    Date<-SE$Date
    Da<-as.Date(Date,format="%m-%d-%Y")
    Price<-SE$Closingprice
Price.SEK<-ts(Price)
    plot(Price.SEK~Da, SE,xaxt = "n",type="l", main="Stockholm 30 Index from August 2011 to March 2015",lwd=1,col=4)
    axis(1, Da, format(Da,"%m-%Y"),cex.axis = .7)
    model=lm(Price.SEK~Da)
    abline(model, col="red")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the comments. I solved the problem as below:

```
SE=read.csv(file="SE.csv",head=TRUE,sep=";")

Date<-SE$Date
Da<-as.Date(Date,format="%m-%d-%Y")
Price<-SE$Closingprice
Price.SEK<-ts(Price)
plot(Price.SEK~Da, SE,xaxt = "n",type="l", main="Stockholm 30 Index from August 2011 to March 2015",lwd=1,col=4)
axis(1, Da, format(Da,"%m-%Y"),cex.axis = .7)
model=lm(Price.SEK~Da)
abline(model, col="red")
```